# Overwrite output in txt file C# in console application

Tags: c#, file

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(indata))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\arjun.txt", true);
    sw.WriteLine("0");
    sw.Close();  
}
```

This is my code. How can I overwrite a result in `arjun.txt` file I need single result.

Answer (score 4):

The `true` part means "append" - either just get rid of it entirely, in which case you'll use the `StreamWriter` constructor overload which overwrites by defalut, or change `true` to `false`.

Or preferably, just use:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\argun.txt", new[] {"0"});
```

When you *can* specify all the data in one go, the convenience methods in [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) are really helpful.